# How to Synapse Pool/DW in Terraform without entire synapse workspace

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-synapse

I am attempting to spin up an azure synapse pool in terraform. At present from the documentation found at: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/synapse_sql_pool, it appears you have to use a synapse workspace, which also includes a datafactory integration and powerbi, etc.

Right now we just want to datawarehouse not all the other bells and whistles. As you can see within the Azure Portal, you are free to spin up a synapse analytics DW with or without a workspace (see the right image in the box, "formerly SQL DW"):
[image]
When you spin that up, you simply have a standalone DW...

Any insight on just getting the datawarehouse as you can in the portal without the workspace and realted?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Terraform guy. As for Synapse, you are referring to the new one that is in preview. The new one has the workspace which supports SQL pools, Sparks clusters and Pipelines. Although they are supported, they are not created when you deploy a Synapse workspace.

So you can go ahead and created the workspace and one SQL Pool and you will get what you're looking for: the data warehouse engine, named SQL Pool.

Some extra notes: there are 2 types of SQL data warehouse in Synapse Analytics: SQL Pools and SQL on demand. The first one is provisioned computing and is the traditional one with all the features. SQL on demand is still in preview, doesn't have all the features and is charged by the terabyte processed by your queries.

Happy data crunching!

Comment: I am aware of everything you are saying, but within the azure portal you can spin up a synapse pool without needing a workspace...if you read the quesiton I asked again, outlined here: " it appears you have to use a synapse workspace, which also includes a datafactory integration and powerbi, etc. Right now we just want to datawarehouse not all the other bells and whistles."

Comment: Hi @Sauron, if I got it right, you're asking how to spin up an Azure SQL DW GEN 2 service. If that is the case, check this link out: https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/5196